# Perl: file test operator without condition

Tags: perl, testing, operators

I have this simple code from [Perl Cookbook](https://www.cs.ait.ac.th/%7Eon/O/oreilly/perl/cookbook/ch09_08.htm) which prints all directories and files recursively:

```
use File::Find;

@ARGV = qw(.) unless @ARGV;
find sub { print $File::Find::name, -d && '/', "\n" }, @ARGV;
```

I do not understand the grammar of `print $File::Find::name, -d`. How is this to interpret? If `-d` tests if `$File::Find::name`is a directory so `-d`is a parameter of the function `print`? Or does Perl explicitly interpret a *standalone* `-d` as `if -d`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the `-d` is a stand alone statement, it tests `$_`. So it is in essence identical to

```
-d $_ && '/'
```

Which says "if file is a directory, return a slash character (to print)". The `sub` code block is used by the `find` function from [`File::Find`](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find), where `$_` contains the file name of the current file.

The commas `,` separate a list of statements that return strings for the `print` statement:

```
print $File::Find::name,   # print the files name
-d && '/',                 # if it is a dir, print /
"\n"                       # print a newline
```

In the [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X) for `-d` (contained in perldoc for `-X` where all the file tests are listed) states:

```
If the argument is omitted, tests $_ ...
```

This applies to all file tests under `-X`.

The reason `&&` can be used this way is that it has a higher precedence than the comma operator `,`. This is documented in [perldoc perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity)